# Are my hours limited on Rstudio even if I've downloaded it on my mac?

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

So I'm an absolute beginner at R and I have been using https://rstudio.cloud/, but yesterday I learned that there is a limit for the number of hours I can work in the free version of R on my browser. I'm just wondering whether downloading RStudio means that I can work more than 20 hours a month. If my hours are limited even after downloading, can I practice coding for free somewhere where my time is not restricted?

Thank you

Comment: RStudio Desktop; Open Source Licence; Free: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/

Comment: As @Pax has suggested, download RStudio desktop. It is free and open source. Or if you want to experiment further, you can also download RStudio daily version from dailies.rstudio.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you download RStudio Desktop, you should be able to work as many hours as you would like. I have RStudio and I work on it about eight hours a day.